# Thread safe compare method

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create a thread safe counter but I'm not sure how to thread safe compare. 
Is the threadCount.get() followed by  '==' operator thread safe ?

```
public class ThreadSafeCounter {

    private final AtomicInteger threadCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    //thread safe
    public void increment() {
        threadCount.getAndIncrement();
    }
    //thread safe
    public void decrement() {
        threadCount.getAndDecrement();
    }
    // is it safe ?
    public boolean compareWith(int integer){
        return threadCount.get() == integer;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you intend to *use* the `compareWith` method? There is no guarantee that its result value will be up to date by the time the calling code has acted on it. In fact, I believe that there is *fundamentally* no way in which this method can be used in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Your right, I will use `incrementAndGet() and decrementAndGet()` as  Andy Turner suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question you need to ask yourself when asking about thread safety is: *what do I mean by "thread-safe"?*

In fact, the question you really need to address is whether the code calling it does so safely.

You can do things with thread-safe data structures that are individually thread-safe, but are not thread safe when taken together.

Using `AtomicInteger` directly:

```
anAtomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
if (anAtomicInteger.get() < 5) {
  // ...
}
```

The two operations here - incrementing and getting - are both thread safe; but - according to *one* definition of thread safety - they're not safe when taken together, because there is a possibility that some other thread has snuck in and incremented `anAtomicInteger` in between the two calls.

*A* solution to this is to use the return value of `incrementAndGet()`:

```
if (anAtomicInteger.incrementAndGet() < 5) {
  // ...
}
```

which is guaranteed to happen atomically, so there is no thread interference there.

The answer to your question - and the solution - depends on what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

It is threadsafe. But it does not guarantee comparsion to be correct, because of race conditions. If we rewrite the code like this, it will be easier to see it.

```
    public boolean compareWith(int integer) {
        int n = threadCount.get();
        // so here, at this point, other thread(s), one, two, ten of them
        // can call increment() or decrement()
        // and so the number n which is used in the following comparsion
        // is no longer the number actually stored in threadCount
        return n == integer;
    }
```